# Copying the functions to global environment

Tags: r, function, environment

I am reading Advanced R by Hadley. I am on Chapter 10 - "Functional Programming." Page 192. This is also available at : http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html under title "Moving lists of functions under global environment."

Here's the code:

```
simple_tag <- function(tag) {
  force(tag)
  function(...) {
    paste0("<", tag, ">", paste0(...), "</", tag, ">")
  }
}
tags <- c("p", "b", "i")
html <- lapply(setNames(tags, tags), simple_tag)
```

My question is that I don't why he says "*I’ve put the functions in a list because I don’t want them to be available all the time. The risk of a conflict between an existing R function and an HTML tag is high...Finally, **you could copy the functions to the global environment with `list2env()`.** You can undo this by deleting the functions after you’re done.*"

This is because if I run the following code:

```
exists("html",envir = globalenv())
```

The above code returns `TRUE`, which means that `html` already exists in the global environment. So, I am not really sure why he says that "...you could copy the functions to the global environment with..."  I recognize that he cannot be wrong. So, I thought of posting this question for experts.

Further, if I run:

```
where("html")
```

I get:

```
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
attr(,"path")
```

From the above code, it sounds like `html` list is in Global Environment already. Isn't it?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`html` is **not** a function, but it is an object saved in your global environment as you demonstrated by `where("html")`. Rather, `html` is a list containing 3 functions.

```
names(html)
# [1] "p" "b" "i"
```

To access one of the functions inside `html` you use: `html$p()` with an argument. See:

```
html$p
# function(...) {
#     paste0("<", tag, ">", paste0(...), "</", tag, ">")
#   }
# <environment: 0x1093fe698>
```

`list2env()` will save the functions inside `html` in the global environment. For example

```
p      # < DOESN'T exist in global environment
# Error: object 'p' not found

list2env(html,envir = globalenv())
p      # < DOES exist in global environment
# function(...) {
#     paste0("<", tag, ">", paste0(...), "</", tag, ">")
#  }
# <environment: 0x1093fe698>
```

However, if there is already a `p` variable or function in the global environment it will be overwritten when you use `list2env`. The risk of overwriting html tags is high because html tag names are very short. So there may already be a `p`, `b`, or `i` function in a package you are using.